# Better way of getting out excess water/oil from food other than paper towels?

Tags: substitutions, equipment, drying

There have been a lot of recipes where I've had to use a bunch of paper towels to get the excess liquid out (making bacon to get out the excess fat, when you're frying foods and want them to be dry). Is there a better way of getting the liquid out without just massing tons of paper towels?

Comment: The answers are likely different for deep frying vs. cooking bacon vs removing excess water.  Can you rephrase or specify?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the time, wrapping something in a cheese cloth & suspending it over a bowl can get a lot of liquid out.

Answer (score 1):

Oils become more viscous as they cool, so keeping your product warm can help keep the oils flowing off it. A wire rack over a sheet pan in a low oven can work quite well for removing oil or water from foods, but ensure your product doesn't dry out too much in the process.